# random forest text classification giving extra rows in prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, text-classification

I am using random forest for text classification. My input data is having 17197 rows.

```
> nrow(sparse_4testing)
[1] 17197
```

I am using

```
set.seed(123)
tweetRand = randomForest(label ~ ., data = train_sparse, importance=TRUE, nTree=500)

predicrRand_test=predict(tweetRand, data=sparse_4testing)
q1=data.frame(ifelse(predicrRand_test>0.5,1,0))
```

The issue is when I am doing a sanity check I am getting extra rows in q1

```
> nrow(q1)
[1] 22373
```

I do not understand the issue. I am new to machine learning. Please help me out.
I have run the model multiple time. Still getting the same issue.

```
> nrow(predicrRand_test)

NULL
> head(predicrRand_test)
            1             3             6             7             9            10 
 1.858321e-01 -8.326673e-17  1.321640e-01  2.222222e-04  2.345304e-02  1.651133e-01 
> head(q1)
   ifelse.predicrRand_test...0.05..1..0.
1                                      1
3                                      0
6                                      1
7                                      0
9                                      0
10                                     1

> length(predicrRand_test)
[1] 22373
```

Comment: Please include the output of the following commands: `nrow(predicrRand_test)`, `head(predicrRand_test)`, `head(q1)`.

Comment: ok. Updating the question.

Comment: OK, since `nrow` gives NULL, what about `length(predicrRand_test)`?

Comment: its 22373. I have updated it in the question.

Comment: OK, should I guess that `nrow(train_sparse)` (i.e. your training data) is also 22373?

Comment: yep .its my training data. and nrow(train_sparse)  is 22373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to wrong argument name in `predict` - it should be `newdata`, not `data` ([docs](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/randomForest/html/predict.randomForest.html)):

```
predicrRand_test=predict(tweetRand, newdata=sparse_4testing)
```

As it is now, your code ignores the `data` argument, and simply returns the predictions on the training set in the `predicrRand_test` dataframe.

Comment: I already tried with newdata argument. Its throwing Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'run' not found. The 'run' feature is missing in new data.

Comment: @RohitHaritash You should post this as your issue, instead of changing the argument. Anyway, it seems that the columns in your training & test sets are not the same; run `colnames(train_sparse)` & `colnames(sparse_4testing)`, and be sure that they are the same (except possibly for `label`, which is not needed in `sparse_4testing`)